# Greenplum 4.3: Filling Missing values

Tags: sql, greenplum

I was trying a SQL using Greenplum Database 4.3.23.0

got a table which has data like

```
ID  ID2    Code Type_ID Status  y_id    Latest_flag
10  10001   205   7        P    114         Y
10  10001   205   7        P    116       NULL
10  10002   205   6        P    116         Y
10  10002   205   6        P    120         Y
```

Desired Output

```
ID  ID2    Code Type_ID Status  y_id    Latest_flag
10  10001   205   7        P    114         Y
**10    10001   205   7        P    115     Y**
10  10001   205   7        P    116       NULL
10  10002   205   6        P    116         Y
**10    10002   205   6        P    117     Y**
**10    10002   205   6        P    118     Y
10  10002   205   6        P    119         Y**
10  10002   205   6        P    120         Y
```

SQL query till now tried

```
with a as
(
select
  id,
  id2,
  generate_series(minAD, maxAD, 1) dt
from (
       select
         id,
         id2,
         min(y_id) minAD,
         max(y_id) maxAD
       from table1
       where id in (10) 
       group by id, id2) a
)
select distinct a.* from (
select
a.id,
a.id2,
a.dt,
code,
type_id,
status,
Latest_flag,
from a
left join (select id,
           id2,
           y_id,
           t1.code,
           t1.type_id,
           t1.status,
           t1.latest_flag
         from table1 t1 where latest_flag = 'Y' 
        ) t1 on
               t1.id = a.id and t1.id2 = a.id2
and y_id <= dt 
order by t1.id, t1.id2, y_id desc) a
```

Output

```
ID  ID2    Code Type_ID Status  y_id    Latest_flag
10  10001   205   7        P    114         Y
10  10001   205   7        P    115         Y
**10    10001   205   7        P    116         Y**
10  10002   205   6        P    116         Y
10  10002   205   6        P    117         Y
10  10002   205   6        P    118         Y
10  10002   205   6        P    119         Y
10  10002   205   6        P    120         Y
```

And also if i have an ID with all y_id values without missing data then no need to do anything. This has to fill gaps based on Lead values which has Latest_flag = 'Y'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you can write a subquery to get `latest_flag IS NULL` from table then `LEFT JOIN` `Generate_series` CTE. If the subquery's `Latest_flag` is `NULL` they will be match, so use `CASE WHEN` expression to filter `Latest_flag`.

Like this:

```
WITH a 
     AS (SELECT a.*, 
                Generate_series(minad, maxad, 1) dt 
         FROM   (SELECT id, 
                        id2, 
                        code, 
                        type_id, 
                        status, 
                        Min(y_id) minAD, 
                        Max(y_id) maxAD 
                 FROM   table1 
                 WHERE  id IN ( 10 ) 
                 GROUP  BY id, 
                           id2, 
                           code, 
                           type_id, 
                           status) a) 
SELECT a.id, 
       a.id2, 
       a.code, 
       a.type_id, 
       a.status, 
       dt  "y_id", 
       CASE 
         WHEN t.id IS NULL 
              AND t.id2 IS NULL THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE  NULL 
       END Latest_flag 
FROM   a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  latest_flag IS NULL) t 
              ON a.id = t.id 
                 AND a.id2 = t.id2 
                 AND a.dt = t.y_id
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/05b28/28